# Magento Router getParams() duplication reach 100 iteration

Tags: magento2.2.2, router, parameter

Not sure why I am having this issue any help appreciated.

[image]

When I check: `$request->getModuleName()`, it is already set and `$request->getControllerName()` is also already set, the only one that isn't set to what I need is `$request->getActionName()`. It is set to `no-route` it should be `view`.

Comment: can you please show your code? and check the log number.

Comment: @MohitRane I have multiple store views 3 to be precise. So I had row data with column `store_id=0` as a default but if have same data for same row `id` with `store_id=3` that's when iteration occurred not sure why still but this is it. So creating  FOR ALL rows with `store_id=1` fixed the issue and it load the page fine. Still a mystery to why though!. could it be that 0 is for the admin and it conflicts ?